# Photoshop JavaScript pauses only when batching

Tags: javascript, action, photoshop, bridge

I have a working script the resized an image based on certain factors. I've integrated this script as part of an action, and when I run it regularly, it goes through the script and continues on to the rest of the action without needing an user input (which is correct).
However, when I run this action in Bridge with a series of images, then it pulls up the image resize box for each individual image, just so the user can click okay. This is NOT what I want to happen.

I'd like to know why it would act differently when batching vs. a one-off image, and how it get it to just run through the process without having the user have to click "enter."